# Doctrine2, single table inheritance and custom type pk

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have custom type as primary key of entity (value object as identity of entity).
For example, `Type1` entity has `Type1Id` VO and `Type2` entity has `Type2Id` VO.

`Type1` and `Type2` mapped to single table, so both classes inherited from `Attribute` entity.

```
Domain\Model\Attribute\Attribute:
    type: entity
    id:
        id:
            column: id
            type: AttributeId
    table: attributes
    inheritanceType: SINGLE_TABLE
    discriminatorColumn:
        name: type
        type: integer
    discriminatorMap:
        1: Domain\Model\Type1\Type1
        2: Domain\Model\Type2\Type2
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
```

So, how you can see, I use `AttributeId` type here, but I want to get `Type1Id` for `Type1` object (and `Type2Id` for `Type2`).

I tried to return appropriate object from method `public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)`, but I didn't found how to detect source class.

Any ideas?

UPD: My solution

Using loadClassMetadata event I can put required type name to `fieldMappings['id']['type']`

```
public function loadClassMetadata(\Doctrine\ORM\Event\LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs)
{
    /** @var ClassMetadataInfo $classMetadata */
    $classMetadata = $eventArgs->getClassMetadata();
    if ($classMetadata->name != $classMetadata->rootEntityName && $classMetadata->rootEntityName === Attribute::class) {
        $pkType = $classMetadata->fieldMappings['id']['type'];
        $type = Type::getType($pkType);
        if ($type instanceof DoctrineSTITypeMapper) {
            $classMetadata->fieldMappings['id']['type'] = $type->mapEntityToType($classMetadata->name);
        }
    }

    return;
}
```